# Why wont my damage system will not work (It doesn't take away health)

Tags: batch-file

So I'm making an RPG and I want my damage system not to be random. I used set health -= %monsterdmg% and then I used set monsterhealth -= %playerdmg% here is my whole code also it isnt done:

```
@echo off
echo Welcome To Notetopia! We Hope You Enjoy!
pause
goto set
:set
set health=100
set monsterhealth=50
set playerdmg=20
set monsterdmg=7
goto home
:home
cls
echo What do you want to do?
echo 1) BATTLE!
echo 2) Exit :'(
set /p a= Select 1 or 2 
if %a%==1 goto battle1
if %a%==2 goto exitmenu
:battle1
set health=100
cls
echo Your Health: %health%
echo Enemie's Health: %monsterhealth%
echo.
echo.
echo Choose:
echo 1) Attack
echo 2) Run Away
set /p b= Select 1 or 2 
if %b%==1 goto attack1
if %b%==2 goto home
:attack1
cls
set health -= %monsterdmg%
set monsterhealth -= %playerdmg%
goto battle1
```

Comment: You have spaces to the left of your operator in your SET statements. And you are missing the `/A` option.

Comment: @Squashman, `set /A` -- opposed to `set` -- can deal with spaces around variable names and operators properly...

Comment: Please provide a specific title for the question! consult this: [ask]...

Comment: Your question title is basically a double negative.

Comment: So... What exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

When using the /A option, which you are missing, you can write your SET statements like this.

```
set /a health-=monsterdmg
set /a monsterhealth-=playerdmg
```

You do not need to use the percent symbols to expand the variable.

Edit.  Here is me playing your game with the clear screens removed. I also removed the `set health=100` in the battle function.  Certainly looks like the math is working correctly.

```
What do you want to do?
1) BATTLE!
2) Exit :'(
Select 1 or 2 1
Your Health: 100
Enemie's Health: 50


Choose:
1) Attack
2) Run Away
Select 1 or 2 1
Your Health: 93
Enemie's Health: 30


Choose:
1) Attack
2) Run Away
Select 1 or 2 1
Your Health: 86
Enemie's Health: 10


Choose:
1) Attack
2) Run Away
Select 1 or 2 1
Your Health: 79
Enemie's Health: -10


Choose:
1) Attack
2) Run Away
Select 1 or 2
```

Comment: ok so It worked for the monsterhealth but not the player health (health) :(

Comment: @OresTV I find that hard to believe. The syntax should be set the same for both and work the same.  I don't have a crystal ball, so I can't see what your code looks like now.

Comment: @OresTV I added my game play to my answer to show you that the math is working.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you loop battle1: you are resetting the health to 100:

```
:battle1
set health=100
```

Every time you attack you loop back to battle1

```
goto battle1
```

I would imagine deleting that instance of `set health=100` will fix your problem.